# How to make a desktop shortcut for opening an SSH tunnel

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, windows-8

I want to put a shortcut on my desktop for a command that launches an SSH tunnel. Here's my tunnel connection:

```
ssh -N -g -D 9999 -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I want this command to be easily accessible from my desktop. How can I make a shortcut for this? My OS is Windows 8. The `ssh` command works on my command line because I installed Gnu On Windows (gow).

Comment: what OS? Are you using plain vanilla ssh of some sort, or putty? Does putting the command as a shell script or batch file work?

Comment: Windows 8. I'm using Gow to make Linux commands available to my windows 8 terminal

Comment: if it doesn't exist, there should be a question as to how to have an ssh tunnel launch with only one click.  I would love to know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple .bat file with content of
`@start ssh -N -g -D 9999 -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
Save that file wherever you want and create a shortcut to it on your desktop.

Comment: what the hell man, it starts hundreds of command line process in a loop. my computer hangs and i need to power it off.

Comment: Ouch. That's not supposed to happen. :/
"@start" is just supposed to launch ssh process so that it does not leave an empty command prompt window hanging. Where did you save that bat file?

Answer (score 0):

Either you called the created batch file "start" or "ssh" and it's actually calling itself; leaving you with lot's of command windows.

Answer (score 0):

Add the configuration to the file you find here `%userprofile%\.ssh\config`, The exact syntax of this file can be found [in the docs](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) but it goes something like

```
Host amazon-ws
   Hostname ec2.compute-1.amazonaws.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
   User ec2-user
```

Make sure to store the key in the .ssh folder and make sure it has the access restricted to you only.
Now you can ssh to the server by typing `ssh amazon-ws` or indeed create a batch script `ssh amazon-ws`. On my (Windows 10) system the `@start` is not required but MS has been messing with PS Microsoft Terminal etc.